# If shorten, python recursion

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

i try to write a short golf code without using letters "eiou" and i found that (a,b)[conditions] is equal to if statement, but i have no idea why it doesn't work.

`a_factaral=lambda x:(a_factaral(x-1)*x,1)[x==0]`

Please for some tips

Comment: your condition would return either `false == 0` or `true == 1`, which are sufficient enough to access a 2 element list **alternatively**

Answer (score 1):

`bool` is a subclass of `int`. `False` is `0` and `True` is `1`.

```
>>> True+True
2
```

Logical predicates like `x==0` return a boolean value.

```
>>> x=0
>>> x==0
True
```

The logical predicate can act as an index of 0 or 1. If the predicate is `False`, the index is `0`. Otherwise, it's `1`.

```
>>> (1, 2)[x!=0]
1
>>> (1, 2)[x==0]
2
```

Your function returns `a_factaral(x-1)*x` if `x` is anything other than `0`, or `1` when `x` has reached `0` (the stopping point for the recursion).

You could ungolf this as follows:

```
def a_factaral(num):
    if num == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a_factaral(num-1) * num
```

Comment: Thank you, but the point is that i can't use these forbidden letters for this task and that's why i try to write this in a different way

Answer (score 0):

`(a_factaral(x-1)*x,1)[x==0]` will calculate the first value first, then decide which value to take out depends on the result of x==0.

`a_factaral=lambda x:((x!=0 and a_factaral(x-1)*x) or 1)` will work for the same function. But in the case you cannot use 'eiou', I have no idea for alternative solution.

Comment: Really thank you! with your help i found the solution:
`a_factaral=lambda x:((x!=0 and a_factaral(x-1)*x) + (0,1)[x==0])`